# Object Creation with a function c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have to find a possible mistake in the following code. Which could be it ?

```
cObject * CreateObject()
{
    cObject t;
    return &t;
}
```

Comment: There are a billion duplicate questions.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning the address from stack.

Answer (score 2):

What would the caller of this function do after calling it ?

What is the lifetime of `t`, and when does it end ?

How would both of these combine with unfortunate consequences ?

> `t` is local to the function, it will die right at the closing brace. The returned pointer can't be used at all, but that's what a caller would probably do, triggering Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

you create a temporary object on stack and return a pointer to it. there is no guarantee it will live after the function is finished.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a point to a local object that does not exist at the end of the function

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a pointer to t, which goes out of scope when you return from the function.  You should create a new pointer inside of the function and return that.

```
cObject *t = new cObject();
return t;
```